# Integrability of $ \exp(-f(x)) $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, definite-integrals

What are the loosest assumptions on $f(x)$ for the distribution $P_f$ whose density $p_f$ wrt lebesgue measure is given by

$$ p_f(x) = \frac{e^{-f(x)}}{ \int_{\mathbb R^d}  e^{-f(y)}dy} \qquad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^d, $$

to be well defined.

For example, $f(x) = \frac{x^\top \Sigma^{-1}x}{2}$ leads to a well defined distribution when  $\Sigma$ is positive definite (Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$). In this case, $f$ is strongly-convex and has Lipschitz continuous gradients.

I am guessing we do not need these two assumptions for $P_f$ to be well defined.

Comment: Not an answer, just a side comment: [log-concave distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Log-concave_distributions) are a class of densities that are studied in certain contexts, they correspond to $f$ being convex in your formulation above.

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, bounded below and $\lim \inf_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\ln{|x|}} > d$, then $P_f$ is well-defined.

Comment: @angryavian Yes. Convexity of $f$ certainly helps to make the integral finite I think. But is convexity sufficient ? I am looking for the most general necessary and sufficient conditions on $f$.